# Launching an application at start-up

Tags: java, android, autostart

I want my application to be automatically launched when the system is started. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need the permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Also, in your manifest, define your service and listen for the boot-completed action:

```
<service android:name=".MyService" android:label="My Service">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.myapp.MyService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<receiver
    android:name=".receiver.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then you need to define the receiver that will get the BOOT_COMPLETED action and start your service.

```
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.myapp.MySystemService");
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

And now your service should be running when the phone starts up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Complete working Example Code,

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.practice" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".AutoStartExampleActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="AutoStart"></receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>
</manifest>
```

AutoStartExampleActivity File

```
package com.practice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AutoStartExampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

BroadcastReceiver Code,

```
package com.practice;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        System.out.println ( "Application Started" );
        // put your TimerTask calling class here

        try
        {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent ( context, AutoStartExampleActivity.class );
            myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println ( " Error while Starting Activity " + e.toString() );
        }
    }
}
```